# Select tag onchange events issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting issue on select tag onChange events.I am selecting value from select tag and value will display in textbox which is declare in script. It's working perfectly when  i removed class="input" from select tag but i don't want to remove class="input".
    Please help me in this.

**Html**

```
<select class="input" name="month" class="style4">
   <option> Product  </option>
   <option> Product1 </option>
   <option> Product2 </option>
   <option> Product3 </option>
   <option> Product4 </option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="No_Inst" id="No_Inst"  >
```

**Css**

```
.input {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 25px
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.style4').change(function(){
  var a = $(this).val();

   if(a == 'Product'){
        $('#No_Inst').val('')
    }

    if(a == 'Product1'){
        $('#No_Inst').val(50)
    }

     if(a == 'Product2'){
        $('#No_Inst').val(100)
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use 2 `class` attributes in your code, but you can do this:

```
<select name="month" class="input style4">
```

There is also no values in your `<option>` set, to do this you can do something like this:

```
<option value="My value">Hello</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't defined an attribute multiple times on a single element, When this happens first attribute overrides the subsequent attributes. This can be refered in [HTML5 spec, 8.2.4.35 Attribute name state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state)

> if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be removed from the token.

You need to set single class attribute.

```
<select class="input style4" name="month">
```

instead of

```
<select class="input" name="month" class="style4">
```

Comment: @RayonDabre, In that scenario `text` of option will be returned

Comment: I read it totally wrong! Time to turn off the machine I guess :(

Answer (score 0):

change your '.input' class to simple 'select' - styles will apply to select DOM element and remove '.input' class from your select tag